How to get step markers/labels on a multislider in react native
I'm working on a project where I need each possible step on the multi slider to be clearly shown. Something like:

I'm using the package @ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider for my multi slider, which supposedly should be able to do this [documentation], and I've even seen an example of something similar here: example. However, I can't seem to get any type of a label or marking to show up for the steps no matter what I try. Does anyone have any advice or know what I could be doing wrong? Thank you!
export default function App() {
  const CustomMarker = () => {
    return (
      <Image
        style={{
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderColor: 'hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 0.6)',
          borderWidth: 3,
          borderRadius: 30,
        }}
      />
    );
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={{
          paddingTop: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          alignSelf: 'center',
        }}>
        <MultiSlider
          //style={{paddingHorizontal:0}}
          containerStyle={{
            flex: 1,
            height: 80,
            width: 250,
          }}
          stepStyles={{
            flex: 1,
            width: 5,
            borderRadius: 8,
            height: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
          }}
          stepsMarkerStyles={{
            flex: 1,
            width: 5,
            borderRadius: 8,
            height: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
          }}
          stepLabelStyles={{
            fontSize: 10,
            width: 5,
            height: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
          }}
          trackStyle={{
            height: 5,
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}
          sliderLength={190}
          optionsArray={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
          min={0}
          max={4}
          step={1}
          showSteps
          showStepMarkers
          //enableLabel
          showStepsLabels
          stepsAs={[
            { index: 0, stepLabel: 0},
            { index: 1, stepLabel: 1},
            { index: 2, stepLabel: 2},
            { index: 3, stepLabel: 3},
            { index: 4, stepLabel: 4},
          ]}
          allowOverlap
          snapped
          //onValueChange={setValue}
          //minimumTrackTintColor="#000000"
          // maximumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
          values={[0, 4]}
          //enableLabel
          customMarker={CustomMarker}
          onValuesChange={(hours) => {
            //setHours(hours)
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}


